# Not getting ajax response in target post fetched through assoc.No matter where i press like button the response is only shown in the first post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook-like, response

I want to show likes on a post whose like button is clicked . Not on the first fetched post.Please help me in this matter .The ajax response code and the fetched part of posts,response page of ajax function.

**try-post.php**

```
<div class='row post_all'>
    <?php
    $query_tp=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM parent_post"enter code here);
        while($data_tp=mysqli_fetch_object($query_tp)){
            $query_by=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM register_1 WHERE register_id='".$data_tp->register_1_id."'");
            while($data_posted_by=mysqli_fetch_object($query_by)){
                $query_p_likes=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM likes WHERE posts_id='".$data_tp->post_id."'");
                    $total_likes=mysqli_num_rows($query_p_likes);
                $query_p_mood=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM parent_post_mood WHERE pp_mood_id='".$data_tp->mood_fk."'");
                while($data_p_mood=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_p_mood)){



?>
    <div class='col-lg-7'>
            <div class="thumbnail"  style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">
            <img src="image_convert/try_post_pic.php?tp_pic=<?php echo $data_tp->post_id;?>" class="img-rounded" alt="Picture here" style="width:100%;height:300px;cursor:pointer;" title="<?php for($i=1;$i<=$counter;$i++){ echo $data_p_mood['fk'.$i]." ";}?>">
      <div class="caption">
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12' style="border-bottom:2px solid #FFFFFF">
                    <h7 style="color:#642C37; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px;"><?php echo $data_tp->post_title;?></h7>
                </br>
                    <p style="font-size:16px; color:#000; text-align:left;"><?php echo $data_tp->post_description;?></p>
                </div><!--col-lg-12-->
                <div class='row' style="padding:0 0 0 5px;">
                    <form>
                    <input type="hidden" id='like_p' value="<?php echo $total_likes;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id='pos_id' value="<?php echo $data_tp->post_id;?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id='username' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['un'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id='userid' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['u_id'];?>">
                    </form>
                    <div class='col-lg-1'>
                        <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up' id='like_btn' onClick="add_like(<?php echo $data_tp->post_id;?>,<?php echo $data_posted_by->register_id;?>,<?php echo $total_likes;?>)" style="color:#2986D8;font-size:22px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;"></span><span class='badge' id="like_bg"></span></p>
                    </div><!--col-lg-4-->
                    <div class='col-lg-2' style="font-size:20px;">
                        <p onClick="comment_p(this,<?php echo $data_tp->post_id;?>)" accesskey='<?php echo $data_tp->post_id;?>' style='cursor:pointer;'>Comment</p>
                    </div><!--col-lg-4-->
                    <div class='col-lg-2' style="font-size:20px;">
                        <a href="#">Share</a>
                    </div><!--col-lg-4-->
                    <div class='col-lg-7' style="padding:6px 0 0 0;"><p style="font-size:14px;">Posted by <i><a href="#"><?php echo ucwords($data_posted_by->f_name)." ".ucwords($data_posted_by->l_name);?></a></i><?php echo " (".$data_tp->post_date.")";?></p></div><!--col-lg-6-->
                </div><!--row-->
              <div id="comment_row"></div><!--comment_row-->
            </div><!--row-->
      </div><!--caption-->
    </div><!--thumbnail-->

    </div><!--col-lg-8-->
</hr>
<?php }/*while most inner*/?>
<?php }/*while inner*/?>
<?php   }/*while*/?>

</div><!--row-->
```

**ajax Function**

```
<script>
function add_like(p_id,user_id,likes){


    var val2=$("#username").val();
    var val3=$("#userid").val();

    //alert(p_id+' '+user_id+' '+val2+' '+val3);
    $.get("ajax/like_add.php",{p_id:p_id,user_id:user_id,val2:val2,val3:val3,likes:likes},function(data){


                $("#like_bg").html(data);
    }); 


    }/*getRec*/
```

**like_add.php**

```
<?php include_once("../connect/dbconnection.php");?>
<?php
    $parent_post_id=$_GET['p_id'];
    $user_id=$_GET['user_id'];
    $sess_uname=$_GET['val2'];
    $sess_id=$_GET['val3'];
    $lik=$_GET['likes'];
    if(!empty($sess_id)){

            $query_like_check=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM likes WHERE posts_id='$parent_post_id' AND register_1_id='$sess_id'");
            $likes_rec=mysqli_num_rows($query_like_check);

            if($likes_rec==0){
    $query_likes=mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO likes(posts_id,register_1_id)VALUES('$parent_post_id','$sess_id')");
                echo "(".$lik.") Like";
    //echo "<h3>".$parent_post_id.$user_id.$sess_uname.$sess_id."</h3>";
                }/*to check if the user have already liked the post*/
                else{

                    $query_likes_del=mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM likes WHERE posts_id='$parent_post_id' AND register_1_id='$sess_id'");
                    $query_again_like=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM likes WHERE posts_id='$parent_post_id' AND register_1_id='$sess_id'");
                    $q_a_l=mysqli_num_rows($query_again_like);
                    echo "(".$q_a_l.") Like";

                }/*else to check if the user have already liked the post*/

                }/*if session id*/
    else{
        echo "Unauthourization of user";

    }/*else session id*/                

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use INNER JOIN in one query instead of using while in while in while and simply use multidimensional arrays. Oh and also use POST method when sending forms. P.S, Your site in very vulnerable right now for SQL injections.